# Recording pen information as sequential images

Tags: dataset, pen, handwriting

I am trying to create a dataset of images of people's handwriting but with the different stages of drawing the letter/word. So for example, when drawing the letter "W", I am looking for separate images of each pen stroke (the first probably being blank, and the last the fully drawn letter). Essentially like the frames of an animation that shows the word being formed.

I have been unable to find an already created dataset online which is why I am looking to make my own.

Do people know of any software that can record the information I am looking for?

The only dataset that I could find that was close to what I wanted was the BRUSH dataset, however it is in words not letters. It was in the form of coordinates which I then plotted and used to recreate the original image I was after.